# Positioning Canvas in window - Tkinter/python

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to position a canvas in a window and have a frame around it?I found only how to position objects inside a canvas.

Comment: Just create a `Frame` and use the frame object as the `Canvas`'s master. What's the problem?

Comment: I have two canvases and I like to position side by side rather than one above the other. Thanks, I'll try frame method.

Comment: Are you using `grid()` or `pack()` as your geometry manager?

Comment: Not at a computer right now to test, but try using something like `canvas1.pack(side=LEFT)` and `canvas2.pack(side=RIGHT)`. I'll be able to give a more detailed answer later.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a frame, then put your widgets in it:

```
f = tk.Frame(...)
c1 = tk.Canvas(f, ...)
c2 = tk.Canvas(f, ...)
c1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
c2.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
```

The above will give you two side-by-side canvases inside a single frame. They will grow and shrink as you resize the containing window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the place() function instead of pack()
and do something like:

```
canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
```

this would place it at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Like fortyTwo102 mentioned, the `place` function will allow you to specify exactly where the canvas is. I thought I'd provide some more examples:

```
# in the center
canvas.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)

# in the bottom right corner
canvas.place(relx=1.0, rely=1.0, anchor=SE)

# in the bottom left corner
canvas.place(relx=0.0, rely=1.0, anchor=SW)

# 30 pixels from the left, 50 from the top
canvas.place(x=30, y=50)
```

Source (and more helpful info): https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_place.htm