# calling tkinter's canvas with a position

Tags: python, windows, canvas, tkinter

When you call tkinter's canvas, you define a height and width:

```
w = Canvas(master, width=ScreenWidth, height=ScreenHeight)
```

To do this, I first get the user's screen resolution, then use that for height and width.  *However*, on windows systems, this overlaps the task bar.  So I try to remedy this by shortening the height.  Unfortunately, Canvas is defined from the the bottom, so this just cleaves the top of the canvas down, rather than the bottom up.  Ideally, I would simply cleave a whole taskbar-sized chunk around the whole canvas to account for users who place their task bar elsewhere.

Is there a way to call canvas with a position so that I can offset it from the task bar in windows OS (or another solution to the general problem of taskbar overlap)?

note: I have tried:

```
w.pack(side="top")
```

and the following similar question didn't seem to help with my situation

[Positioning Canvas in window - Tkinter/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111679/positioning-canvas-in-window-tkinter-python)

Comment: What do you mean by "Casvas is defined from the bottom"? That makes no sense. The size has no relation to the location on the screen.

Comment: My assumption, based on the bheavior, is that it positions the bottom left corner of the canvas in the bottom left of the screen.  I assume this because when I define a smaller height, it shrinks top down, not the bottom up.

Comment: I can see how you might draw that conclusion, but it's an incorrect assumption. Tkinter doesn't "remove" or "add" to the top, bottom, left or right. The size is simply a size, not relative to anything. How and where you place it in the container, and how that container is managed determines where on the screen it appears. You probably have a window manager that simply places each new window lower on the screen by default.

Comment: ok, thanks, that helps.  Between your correction and answer, I'm working out the solution and will respond to your answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to place a canvas relative to any position on a screen, *per se*. A canvas is not an independent window. All you can do is place it somewhere relative to it's containing window.

However, you have absolute control over the topmost window (either an instance of `Toplevel`, or an instance of `Tk`) using the `geometry` method. That method allows you to specify the width and height of the window, and the location of the window on the screen.

So, if you're trying to put a canvas at a specific location, you must put the window at that location, then make sure the canvas fills the window.

Comment: perfect, thank you.  A note to future n00bs, the geometry method takes a string in a special format defined [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/x9867-window-geometry-methods.htm) and not a list of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

To position it in the center, as @Bryan Oakley stated, use something along the lines of:

```
# note: 'master' is a tk.Toplevel() or a tk.Tk()

w = Canvas(master, width=ScreenWidth, height=ScreenHeight)
w.pack()

master.geometry("+{xPos}+{yPOS}".format(xPos = 0, yPos = 0))
```